# How to disable keybinding in DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I wan to use [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) (a jQuery-plugin) for displaying data.
Installation and setup is done, searching in my data via DataTables works fine so far.
I am using DataTables v1.10.12, my jQuery is stuck to 1.9.1.

I want to disable bindings of events, or have no events at all - how can I do this?

**Background**

I am developing a plugin for a 3rd party application. This application encapsulates jQuery, I cannot change this.

When using DataTables, I am running into an error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Right now, I am working around this issue by

```
jQuery("#my-table").DataTable({"ordering": false, "paging":false});
```

I have no clue, where this error comes from, but I have the stack-trace and I am seeing, if I would not bind some events, this problem would not occur. Of course, this is not a good solution, but for time being the only, I can use.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
jQuery.extend.map   @   batch.js?analytics-enabled=true&bamboo-nps-dark-feature=true&devtoolbar=true&is-server-instance=tru…:876
(anonymous function)    @   batch.js?analytics-enabled=true&bamboo-nps-dark-feature=true&devtoolbar=true&is-server-instance=tru…:30520
keyHandler  @   batch.js?analytics-enabled=true&bamboo-nps-dark-feature=true&devtoolbar=true&is-server-instance=tru…:30523
jQuery.event.add    @   batch.js?analytics-enabled=true&bamboo-nps-dark-feature=true&devtoolbar=true&is-server-instance=tru…:4926
jQuery.event.add    @   batch.js?analytics-enabled=true&bamboo-nps-dark-feature=true&devtoolbar=true&is-server-instance=tru…:10312
...
jQuery.fn.extend.bind   @   batch.js?analytics-enabled=true&bamboo-nps-dark-feature=true&devtoolbar=true&is-server-instance=tru…:7673
_fnBindAction   @   jquery.dataTables.js:6533
_fnSortAttachListener   @   jquery.dataTables.js:6154
_fnBuildHead    @   jquery.dataTables.js:3210
_fnInitialise   @   jquery.dataTables.js:4682
(anonymous function)    @   jquery.dataTables.js:1339
```

With:

```
jquery.dataTables.js:6526   function _fnBindAction( n, oData, fn )
jquery.dataTables.js:6527   {
jquery.dataTables.js:6528       $(n)
jquery.dataTables.js:6529           .bind( 'click.DT', oData, function (e) {
jquery.dataTables.js:6530                   n.blur(); // Remove focus outline for mouse users
jquery.dataTables.js:6531                   fn(e);
jquery.dataTables.js:6532               } )
jquery.dataTables.js:6533           .bind( 'keypress.DT', oData, function (e){
```

Comment: Wouldn't off() work? give it DT selector and pass events

Comment: Tried it, as described at https://datatables.net/reference/api/off() - does not help.
My TypeError occurs from DataTables-constructor. I did not expect this to help, as events are turned after my error occured - but thanks for input!

Comment: Show HTML markup for `#my-table`, most likely it has mismatch of columns in the `thead` and `tbody` elements or some other structural problems.

Comment: I upload HTML source to http://pastebin.com/2As3fvBK. Search for table with id "checkstyle-result-table" (I build a minimal example showing my error). 
Please be reminded, I am stuck to develop within a framework (Atlassian Bamboo).

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem today with jira.
It's actually a bug in Atlassian AUI, as they overwrite some code in jquery-hotkey, see https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/browse/AUI-1283
and https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/aui/diff/src/js/jquery/jquery.hotkeys.js?diff2=3a600c290f9c
DataTables tries to register it's own hotkeys and fails.

To fix it, you can

- Update your bamboo to a newer version
- Remove the keybinding from DataTables, that means deleting the ' .bind( 'keypress.DT'...' in jquery.dataTables.js#_fnBindAction

Comment: Thanks for input, I gonna have a look at it.